# Centering 3 Images with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, centering

There are a group of images that need to be centered horizontally on the same line under different sections. One I want to be a special type of image that actually comes from an  tag.

I need all of these images, including the input tag image, centered in their respective div at all times.

Right now my markup is basically:

```
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
       <h1>Some centered text</h1>
        <div class="image-container">   
           <img class="contact-images" src="image1.png" />
           <img class="contact-images" src="image2.png" />
           <div class="email-image">
                    <form action="contact-team-member.php" method="POST">
                        <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="1" VALUE="one">
                        <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="2" VALUE="two">
                        <input type="image" class="contact-images" src="image3.png" alt="Submit Form" />
                    </form>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

With CSS:

```
.image-container {
    text-align: center;
}
.contact-images {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

This is the CSS I found recommended online in forums when I googled solutions to the problem, unfortunately it does not work for me.

Unfortunately the images are centered but all stacked on top of each other -- not in one horizontal line. I think this is caused by the input image.

Here is an actual image from my website:

[image]

Comment: just a typo in my question! sorry, its fixed now @misterManSam

Comment: website is http://texasca.com/team dont want to share it to broadly but I'll put the link up as a comment for now

Comment: Start with: line 67 of team.css `.employee-profile img` is currently `display:block` change to inline block

Comment: Actually, as this question can't really be reproduced (the code snippet provided works well) I will vote to close. No bother :) Please remove any redundant comments :)

Comment: you're right, I'll close it down. My apologies. thank you for all of your help though

Comment: No worries, right-click and "Inspect Element" in the future to troubleshoot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/3vg6h953/1/)

Give width in `%` so that they don't go to bottom on browser re-size the `width` of the parent will also decrease so `%` will help check above fiddle

```
.contact-images {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    width:20%;
    height:auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the dots in your css rules...

```
.image-container {
    text-align: center;
}
.contact-images {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: that was just a mistake in typing the question, my actual CSS has the dots, thanks for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 0):

use this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ubr098v/)

```
.image-container {
    text-align: center;
}
.contact-images {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I don't understand why it works in Fiddle on not on my website :(

Comment: can you please provide the link to your website?

Comment: @Zach Cook You are using twitter boostrap you don't need the extra css just use grid `classes` and offset from boostrap

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/0sqkpg9t/ You forgot to add the dots in your css

```
.image-container {

background-color:gold;
width:500px;
height:220px;
text-align: center;
}
.contact-images {

width:200px;
height:200px;
display: inline-block;
}
```